# How to register NSItemProvider for drag and drop in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, drag-and-drop

I’m trying to implement drag and drop functionality in an Objective-C project for the iPad. The principles seem to be straight forward enough, but the examples are all in Swift and I'm simply unable to register the `NSItemProvider` correctly, because I hit a roadblock on the `loadHandler` completion handler.

In Swift it would be something like this:

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()      
itemProvider.registerDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypePlainText as String, visibility: .all) { completion in
            completion(data, nil)
            return nil
        }
```

In Objective-C the syntax would be something like this:

```
NSItemProvider *itemProvider = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem:data      typeIdentifier:kUTTypePlainText];

[itemProvider registerDataRepresentationForTypeIdentifier:kUTTypePlainText
                                            visibility:NSItemProviderRepresentationVisibilityAll
                                                 loadHandler:
```

???What?

I can't figure out what the syntax for the completion handler should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
NSItemProvider* provider = [NSItemProvider new];
[provider registerDataRepresentationForTypeIdentifier:UTI
          visibility:NSItemProviderRepresentationVisibilityAll
          loadHandler:^NSProgress * _Nullable(void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(NSData * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable)) {

    NSProgress* progress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:100];
    // do work and call completion handler when done
    return progress;

}];
```

Comment: Thank you, Nik. Works a charm!